# Golang: UDP packet forwarding to multiple ports

Tags: go, multiprocessing, udp

Need help or suggestions in terms of how to do packet forwarding correctly. I received UDP packets from another server and I want to write a function to send the same packets to different processes running on the same machine.

From Server --> Client(Main Process) --> Process 1, Process 2, Process 3

Example Code: For Sending to one service Running on different Ports.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

var message = make([]byte, 1024)

func main() {
    s, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "127.0.0.1:6001")
    c, err := net.DialUDP("udp4", nil, s)
    // c, err := net.ListenUDP("udp4", s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }

    defer c.Close()

    message := []byte("message")

    for {
        _, err = c.Write(message)
        fmt.Println(">>> Request packet sent to: 127.0.0.1:6001")

        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }

        // for {
        // b := make([]byte, 1024)
        fmt.Println("waiting for data")
        n, addr, err := c.ReadFromUDP(message)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(addr)
        fmt.Println(string(message[:n]))
        SendtoAnotherPort(6002, message[:n])
    }

}

// SendtoAnotherPort sends a packet to another port
func SendtoAnotherPort(port int, msg []byte) {
    s, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "127.0.0.1:6002")
    c, err := net.DialUDP("udp4", nil, s)
    // c, err := net.ListenUDP("udp4", s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        panic(err)
    }
    _, err = c.WriteTo(message, s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}
```

Could this be the correct way of doing it? Or Any other suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure you need to code that? e.g. iptables can do this already. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553334/setting-up-udp-packets-to-two-different-destinations-using-iptables-and-prerouti) for example.

Comment: why don't use "io.Copy`?

Comment: I tried using UDP mirror and the solution works for me. I will try IP tables too